# Python serial connection lost after sending data

Tags: python, arduino, python-multithreading, pyserial

I'm developing a python application using the serial module. Instead of the usual blocking implementation I use threaded implementation in this library. Besides, in fact I exchange data with Arduino and expect to receive from it a package of data bytes, so I use a Packetizer object to handle packets from arduino asynchronously. Now I am faced with a problem: when I send data to the serial port - the connection is lost.

```
class Keyboard:
    port = None
    transport = None
    protocol = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        for port in list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports()):
            if "VID:PID=2341:8037" in port[2]:
                self.port = serial.Serial(port[0], 115200)

        class SerialConnector(serial.threaded.Packetizer):

            TERMINATOR = 0x04

            def handle_packet(self, packet):
                print(packet)

            def connection_made(self, transport):
                print("Connection established")

            def connection_lost(self, exc):
                print("Connection lost")

        connector = serial.threaded.ReaderThread(self.port, SerialConnector)
        connector.start()
        self.transport, self.protocol = connector.connect()

    def load(self):
        self.transport.write(b"C")
```

First of all I create an instance of this object. Next, I call load() method of it and then I recieve "Connection lost" message in console. Instead of this, Arduino must send to me package of bytes in response. Arduino works properly, I tried to send "C" symbol in arduino serial terminal and I got the proper response.

Comment: The reason that the connection is lost is probably an exception in the `threaded` module. This exception is stored in the `exc` argument of the `connection_lost` method. Add `print(exc)` to the method to see the exception. This might give you a hint what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped! I added `print(exc)` and recieved `'int' does not support the buffer interface` error. After that I replaced `write(b"C")` with `write(0x43)` BUT, program sends to device 67 bytes that are not displaying in my console and when I send data to python - it gives the same error and closes port. What can be the reason for such behavior?